# How can I sort results by popular item on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I ran into some problem about sorting.
If I want to do sorting on ElasticSearch by frequently found results, how can I do it?

For example, I have 3 docs that contain keyword like this.

```
{
    title: "red shirt"
},
{
    title: "blue shirt"
},
{
    title: "green shirt"
}
```

and I usually find "green shirt" so when I do sorting by popular items then it will shows "green shirt" on top of results.

Now, I have an idea for solving is when I've found the results I will use "update_by_query" to update "popular_score" like below

```
"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.popular_score++",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
```

This means I must call API to update popular_score every search requests, but I don't think it's good!

What should I do about this,

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you need to boost your keyword

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping-boost.html

Here you will found doc related to keyowrd boost

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title": {
                "query": "quick brown fox",
                "boost": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think boosting will be effects on current search, but score won't be memorized on ElasticSearch and when I do sorting on next times it's not sort by popular item correctly. Or I have misunderstanding about this?

Comment: function_score is use for search by popularity  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html

Comment: but I don't have some field like "votes" T_T. I want ElasticSearch automatically calculates by itself.

Comment: Use have 'title' field or field that content search data, just pass